# Makefile to compile java in directories

Tags: java, linux, makefile, compilation

I would like to create makefile that will compile java files which are in specific directory. Here is what I've got:

```
JCC = javac
JCR = java
JFLAGS =
    -source 1.6 \
    -target 1.6 \
    -d out

main: folder all

all:
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) src/com/company/*.java

folder:
    mkdir out
```

But once I use **make** command in my main directory it says:

> make: *** Missing objects. Stop.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for help.

--UPDATE--
I've tried to do:

```
main:
    mkdir out
    javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 src/com/company/*.java -d out
```

But still:

> "No rule to make target 'mkdir', needed by 'main'.  Stop."

---SOLUTION---
Don't write makefiles in gedit. It makes wrong tabulators. Use nano or sth else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at writing makefiles, but I recently used something like this, maybe it will be enough for you to modify for your needs, first it compiles the code and then it packages it to jar:

```html
all:
  mkdir out
  javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 src/main/java/com/my/package/*.java -d out
  jar cfm My.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF out/com/my/package/*.class
```

Comment: .class would be fair enough for me, but it still doesn't work (look update)

Comment: Why `main:` not `all:`? I have it like in my answer right now, and it works, compiled classes are in newly created `out` folder.

Comment: It turned out that gedit makes tabulators wrong and that was the cause. Rewrote it to nano and worked. Anyway thanks for help :)